# What is SEGV_MAPERR?

Tags: linux, posix, segmentation-fault, coredump

What is `SEGV_MAPERR`, why does it always come up with `SIGSEGV`?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

There are two common kinds of [SEGV](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.8/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L228), which is an error that results from an invalid memory access:

1. A page was accessed which had the wrong permissions. E.g., it was read-only but your code tried to write to it. This will be reported as [`SEGV_ACCERR`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.8/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L231).
2. A page was accessed that is not even mapped into the address space of the application at all. This will often result from dereferencing a null pointer or a pointer that was corrupted with a small integer value. This is reported as [`SEGV_MAPERR`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.8/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L230).

Documentation of a sort (indexed Linux source code) for `SEGV_MAPERR` is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/SEGV_MAPERR.

Comment: Why is http://stackoverflow.com/a/1000010/358475 marked as the answer when this one is more complete and helpful?

Comment: The question and other answer are much older than my answer. I did edit the other answer to improve it at least.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the circumstances that differentiate these from EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception types.  e.g. is the page mapped but not allocated (/ recently deallocated)?

Comment: One example of `SEGV_MAPERR` is stack overflow (no pun intended). :D

Comment: There are even more SEGV types: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L223

Comment: @tomasz Yes, the last version with just the two was 3.18: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.18.78/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L200

Answer (score 42):

It's a segmentation fault. Most probably a dangling pointer issue, or some sort of buffer overflow.

`SIGSSEGV` is the signal that terminates it based on the issue, segmentation fault.

Check for dangling pointers as well as the overflow issue.

Enabling core dumps will help you determine the problem.

Comment: how do you enable core dump?