# PJSIP library crash: "signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)" in "libpjsua2.so"

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I got this error in my production version of application on Google Play reported by a user:

> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) libpjsua2.so
>
> **backtrace:**
>
> native: pc 00000000001bd4e8  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 00000000001bd6b7  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pj_timer_heap_schedule_w_grp_lock+26)
>       native: pc 000000000016497f  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 0000000000164e53  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 0000000000165db7  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 000000000015dc1d  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 000000000015f57b  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_resolve+1058)
>       native: pc 000000000015e9cd  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pjsip_endpt_send_request_stateless+92)
>       native: pc 0000000000165087  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 0000000000165173  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 0000000000166943  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pjsip_tsx_send_msg+86)
>       native: pc 0000000000166b8b  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pjsip_endpt_send_request+86)
>       native: pc 00000000001503db  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pjsip_regc_send+206)
>       native: pc 0000000000138daf  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pjsua_acc_set_registration+1118)
>       native: pc 000000000013b0bb  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 00000000001bd7d1  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pj_timer_heap_poll+124)
>       native: pc 000000000015d1f1  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pjsip_endpt_handle_events2+34)
>       native: pc 0000000000140d2d  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>   (pjsua_handle_events+32)
>       native: pc 0000000000140d51  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 00000000001b7bf9  /data/app/domain.package.appname-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so
>       native: pc 0000000000047423  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
>       native: pc 0000000000019efd  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)

How to understand this error? Unfortunately I can not reproduce this issue. I guess it has to do with background registration of account, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Exception occurs between your **Android application** and **libpjsua2.so** library.

So the error is occured while registering the account. And also Exception stated while *pjsua_acc_set_registration*. so check where are the places, you are going to registering account using **pjsua_acc_set_registration(acc_id,PJ_TRUE)**.

> This can occur while you are trying to register the account, that
>   account (*acc_id*) doesn't exist in your PJSIP Library.

Just try this one and I'm not 100% sure.

[What is SEGV_MAPERR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000002/what-is-segv-maperr)

The above link clearly shows that,

A page was accessed that is not even mapped into the address space of the application at all. This will often result from dereferencing a null pointer or a pointer that was corrupted with a small integer value. This is reported as SEGV_MAPERR.

So, its shows that it passing the null pointer something into your library file libpjsua2.so .

Check the places pjsua_acc_set_registration method you called and it has any chances to call this method without your PJSIP account. Sometimes, if garbage collector cleans your memory of all PJSIP user details and it tries to register the account using pjsua_acc_set_registration.

Comment: I made some changes in my app logic for registration. Registration is done from a background service, so we will see if that helps. I published app to see if I get any crash reports this time. Thank you!