# How to load multiple sound with Oboe

Tags: android, oboe

I have some issue with Oboe when I trying to load more than 90 - 100 sounds the app Crash with :

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 32081 (AudioTrack), pid 32003
```

I have test to play only one of them all and all works fine. It crash only when I try to load a lot of files.
For load all of them I juste user an array of Player :

```cpp
std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<Player>, 16>,19> mSoundKit;

mSoundKit[instrument][intensity] = std::make_unique<Player>(mClapSource);

mMixer.addTrack(mSoundKit[instrument][intensity].get());
```

I try to upgrade the maxTracks of the app :

```
constexpr uint8_t kMaxTracks = 255;
```

But I just have a crash now for loading more than 130-140 sounds

The same crash with renderAudio :

```
mTracks[i]->renderAudio(mixingBuffer, numFrames);
```

from AudioReady :

```
mMixer.renderAudio(outputBuffer+(oboeStream->getChannelCount()*i), 1);
```

I do something wrong ?

I have to load 230 240 sound for play them at same time.
Can I have help for that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to debug your code without seeing a full stack trace and source code (could you post a link to a github project?), however, the most likely cause is that you are [dereferencing a null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000002/what-is-segv-maperr) somewhere.

Some possible causes:

1. Are you sure `kMaxTracks` is high enough? You have a 16x19 2D array which equates to 304 possible players. Adding more than `kMaxTracks` tracks will result in undefined behaviour.
2. Are the `Player` objects all successfully created? If not, there's a problem with your source files or the loading process.
3. How big are these files? You might be running out of memory.

Comment: I just find that all the sound files need to be in 48 000 rates. They are in 44 100. I just have to find a solution to convert all my sound with a free solution without lose quality. Thanks again @donturner