# Log to Logcat before a SIGSEGV /SEGV_MAPERR crash

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a native library that has a native crash. The crash doesn't happen consistently and I can't reproduce it. I have access to Google breakpad's minidump and last few thousands LogCat lines from the users. The method doesn't crash all the time so I suspect perhaps it crashes because of specific param values that I haven't checked. Unfortunately this is a method that's called a lot so I can't log to LogCat all the time.

I understand that `try/catch` doesn't work for `SIGSEGV`. But is there a similar mechanism?

Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436368/4092412.

Comment: You posted the only thing that might work.  But the seg error message will tell you everything that does.  I'm not sure what you hope to capture.

Comment: The answers on the question you linked are utterly horrendous - don't try using any of them.  Some of the comments there akin to "Calling `printf()` in a signal handler is safe!" are utterly ***WRONG***.  A SEGV because of heap corruption is common, so the SEGV happens with the heap locked.  And `printf()` usually uses the heap.  See where that's going?  Every one of the answers to that question are, to paraphrase a commenter there, ***TOYS*** not suited for real use.

Comment: I'm not a C/C++ expert. Is it possible to check if an object has been de-referenced in C++? According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28116503/4092412, I'm thinking I can try checking each variable and parameter to see which one has been de-referenced, and print to LogCat accordingly.

Comment: Also I found out that it's not possible to check if a pointer has been dereferenced?