# Game Crashing When Loading Main Scene On Some Android Devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

Hey guys I'm in desperate need of help with this problem. We have an game built and released to the Google Play Store. The game runs perfectly fine on my phone and many others. The issue is that the game crashes when loading our main scene only on a minority percentage of Android devices. This is still big a problem though.

Some devices that have the problems:

- Samsung Galaxy A20
- Samsung Galaxy A32
- Oppo A53s
- Motorola moto e
- Redmi 9
- Samsung Galaxy A02s
- Samsung Galaxy A11

There is some info we've gathered that makes this even more confusing:

- The logcat does not show any major error when crashing.
- We added Debug.Log and Try Catch to Awake of all manager scripts We
  also made the player manager first in Unity's Script Execution Order
  These logs and Try Catch are not showing in the logcat (Scripts not
  even being executed?)
- The game does not crash when only the player manager object is in the
  scene When we add EITHER the enemy manager OR the UI Manager the game
  will crash Both of these managers will draw something on the screen
  whereas the player manager does not show anything on the screen. (Is
  it an issue with graphics settings?)

We tried removing most third party SDKs but it still crashed

- Facebook SDK
- Firebase SDK
- Unity Mediation Beta
- We have a loading scene that does not crash

Other relevant info:

- Unity 2021.2.13f
- We tried a couple other Unity version but it still crashed.
- Target API level 30

I'll keep adding more info the post once we gain more. If anyone has any ideas or has experienced something like this then I would really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you also provide part of code where you draw stuff on the screen? What do you mean by "draw"? It is like a pen or is it loading texture? Or is it UI thing? Could you provide the part of code where you suspicious? Are there any similarities on the crashing devices? Like API level, android version, screen sizes or anything?

Comment: Since it is released on Google play, could you send a link to the game if it is not a secret, so I can try it on my own?

Comment: Sorry I think saying "draw" something on the screen was the wrong word. I just meant that they actually spawned objects with sprites attached to them. The Player Manager does not have anything visual on the screen.

Here is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes&hl=en&gl=US

The android versions are varying. The screen sizes are also different. Can't seem to find out what the similarities are in the devices.

Comment: Ok. It crashes for me as well. It shows loading screen and crashes. Try removing sections of your code to see which part is causing this. And have you tried rewriting your code but this time a little different? And also try this: create new project and copy/paste all the assets to your new project and build. Maybe it won't crash then (it sometimes solves the problem).

Comment: Also before crashing it freezes. Make sure that none of your loops are infinite

Comment: Ok, I think it returns null error. Always check if object is accessible before accessing it. if(object!=null). Also it returns error similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000002/what-is-segv-maperr      I think that in some devices it can't access a specific object because it returns null. So it crashes

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for testing it for me! Where are you seeing that error? Is it showing up in the logcat for you?

Comment: I have Redmi s2 (2018 MIUI 10 Android 8). When an app crashes it asks if I want to send the MI team a crash report. There's a link "view summary" where it shows what error actually appeared. If it doesn't appear for you try turning on developer mode. Or I can send screenshots of errors as an answer if you want

Comment: Ok I was able to copy the message and post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @YGreater and his crash logs I was able to narrow the issue down to a graphical problem. It had to do with how some phones loaded the textures from our game. Had to rework the way that we loaded some resources and changed some references. It works now!

Comment: Congratulations 

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your app and I think this will be useful for you. PAY ATTENTION to

```
>>> com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes <<<
uid: 11015
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), 
fault addr 0x60
Cause: null pointer dereference
```

Part of the error. I think It can't get access to something or gets null.

Full error message:

java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 2021.2.13f1
Device model      : Xiaomi Redmi S2
Device fingerprint: xiaomi/ysl/ysl:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/V10.3.1.0.OEFMIXM:user/release-keys
Build Type        : Release
Scripting Backend : IL2CPP
ABI               : armeabi-v7a
Strip Engine Code : true

Caused by: java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2021.2.13f1 (90b6766da538)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/ysl/ysl:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/V10.3.1.0.OEFMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
Timestamp: 2022-08-08 13:57:24+0500
pid: 28532, tid: 28604, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes <<<
uid: 11015
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x60
Cause: null pointer dereference
r0  00000048  r1  00000000  r2  00000008  r3  40000000
r4  82386020  r5  01900100  r6  00000002  r7  80ed8c60
r8  00000001  r9  00000000  r10 00000000  r11 82379668
ip  a4fa3d5c  sp  77f3e4c8  lr  8a21e108  pc  8a21e108

backtrace:
#00 pc 007d8108  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#01 pc 007d6cd8  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#02 pc 007d7c80  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#03 pc 007d7858  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#04 pc 00590ad0  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#05 pc 00536278  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#06 pc 0010c7f5  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#07 pc 00126821  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#08 pc 00126925  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#09 pc 004e981c  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#10 pc 00634097  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#11 pc 00634d7f  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#12 pc 0062e4a7  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#13 pc 001baa23  /data/app/com.HappyHedgehog.IdleBounceHeroes-Zj0Q3i8jZbOmRJDrVblF9Q==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BuildId: cf27a02556a0eed15af1ae5beb2cbe0adf18284a)
#14 pc 00047a1f  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22) (BuildId: 455f9e023a86fc21ca8f19f464f56db2)
#15 pc 0001b31d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32) (BuildId: 455f9e023a86fc21ca8f19f464f56db2)

```
at libunity.0x7d8108(Native Method)
at libunity.0x7d6cd8(Native Method)
at libunity.0x7d7c80(Native Method)
at libunity.0x7d7858(Native Method)
at libunity.0x590ad0(Native Method)
at libunity.0x536278(Native Method)
at libunity.0x10c7f5(Native Method)
at libunity.0x126821(Native Method)
at libunity.0x126925(Native Method)
at libunity.0x4e981c(Native Method)
at libunity.0x634097(Native Method)
at libunity.0x634d7f(Native Method)
at libunity.0x62e4a7(Native Method)
at libunity.0x1baa23(Native Method)
at libc.__pthread_start(void*)(__pthread_start:22)
at libc.__start_thread(__start_thread:32)
```

Comment: Thanks again. Could I add you on Discord or something? I've pushed some changes to our internal testing but it still crashes on our test device. I was wondering if the crash log you receive is the same with our latest internal build.

Comment: i have discord. But I live in Turkmenistan. So many sites, servers, platforms and even vpns are blocked. that's why i can't use discord until i find a working vpn. but you could upload it to google drive and send link to my email yagshygreater@gmail.com . Looking forward to help you with solving your issue.

Comment: I just sent you a link to the internal testing. Thanks again!